# Class not found Exception : Unknown Class Name

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-play, cocos2d-x

My app is crashing and it happening randomly on random device. Crash log shown on Play shows something like following. But doesn't specify class name which isn't found.

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:2713)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800 (ActivityThread.java:153)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1428)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:148)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5437)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:738)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:628)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
       at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:511)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:469)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:2708)
```

App compile sdk api is 24, tool is Eclipse. It is cross platform project build on Cocos2d-x version is 2.2.6, and I can't update it to latest version of cocos2d-x. I need solution for this version.

Comment: How do you build your app? Are you using cocos console?

Comment: I have the same situation, App is built on Cocos2DX and it cant be moved to newer version and same Crash is reported number of times on Google Play Console. App is build by Eclipse, no solution found till now.

Comment: Does this crash happen across all supported sdk levels ?

Comment: @Makalele app is build using eclipse.

Comment: @IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII yes crash happens across all supported sdk levels...

Comment: Try running with cocos console.

Comment: @Makalele this exception is not produced when I run on test devices, users are facing these exceptions & GooglePlay console log is showing these.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had to deal with the same thing. The issue is that how Google Play Console displays the ANRs and crashes has changed. From the page:

> ANRs & crashes data source changed
>
> This section shows all ANRs & crashes collected from Android devices whose users have reported individual crash and ANR events. As of 17 May 2017, the new section shows all ANRs & crashes collected from Android devices whose users have opted in to automatically share usage and diagnostics data and has a higher volume of reports. [Learn more] *(link)*
>
> [View new ANRs & crashes] *(link)*

Users that report crashes will show the full thing. Automatic collection seems to remove the first line or so.

There are two ways of getting the old (full) user-submitted reports:

**1) Find the link to the previous version**

It's not obvious, but at the top of the *ANRs & crashes* section, there's the text

> This section shows all ANRs & crashes collected from Android devices whose users have opted in to automatically share usage and diagnostics data. The [previous section]*(link)* shows all ANRs & crashes collected from Android devices whose users have reported individual ANR & crash events and has a smaller volume of reports.

Click on the *previous section* link. You can now click on the crash to get the full crash report, as well as the user messages passed along.

**2) Download the crash report**

- Go to the main Google Play Console screen (https://play.google.com/apps/publish/?account=XXXX#AppListPlace).
- On the left hand side, there's the links "All application", "Game services", etc. Click on the one that says "Download reports"
- Click on "Crashes & ANRs" and select your app if you have more than one
- You'll be show a screen that lets you download a CSV of your crash reports. Inside, you'll find the classname that's missing, as well as a link to the crash report with the full stack trace

Comment: Just to note, this is only helpful, if a user manually submits the crash that you're interested in - i.e., you can have 1000 auto-submitted crashes, but I haven't found a way to access the missing info on those

Comment: In my case this crash occurs when app is in back ground & stops working due to some unknown reasons, user doesn't know about the crash because when he taps on the icon it's like fresh starting the app.